# window.open('url', '_self') not working

Tags: javascript, html, self, window.open, current-page

So i wanted to open a new page replacing the current one, i found that the method should be putting the second parameter on _self but nothing happen...
By the way, if i use the _blank parameter or i left it empty it opens in a new page. The rest of the function works good, but i can't find a way to close the current page and open the new one that i want.
Here is the javascript and the html buttom that call the function.

```
    <button id="rgstr_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onClick="store()">Register</button>   
      <script>
                function store() {
                localStorage.setItem('nome', nome.value);
                localStorage.setItem('pw', pw.value);
                window.open('url', '_self');
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just set `window.location.href`?

Comment: Does this button reside in a ```form``` tag? In that case add a ```type="button"``` attribute, otherwise it also submits the form (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), which may clash with your own page loading efforts.

Comment: You are right man thank you very much now it works

Comment: ok, I added it as an answer then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Button has a `type` attribute which defaults to `submit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type
While this does not affect "everyday" buttons, if the button resides in a `form`, this way it will submit the form, and result in some page loading, which clashes with your own attempt.
  You can just add a `type="button"` attribute to the `button` to avoid that:

```
<button id="rgstr_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="store()">Register</button>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

`windows.open()` opens the URL in a new window.

To replace the URL in the current window, use:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

Comment: Still nothing... it looks like the page reloads because it deletes the fields of the form that is in the page but it doesn't open any page